# Why am I receiving a null value for this.nextElementSibling?

Tags: javascript, null, this

I'm new to Javascript and I'm trying to figure out why the .nextElementSibling is not grabbing the next element in the listHere's my HTML structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="User1" class="area-left">
        <h1>User 1: Sylvr</h1><br>
    </div>
    <div id="ItemTree" class="area-center">
        <h1>Bolt: Item Tree</h1><br>
        <ul class="col_ul">
            <li><span>[+]</span> Bolt
                <ul>
                    <li>Zap</li>
                    <li><span>[+]</span> Gift of Bolt</li>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Icy Runestone</li>
                            <li>Superior Sigil of Air</li>
                            <li><span>[+]</span> Gift of Metal</li>
                            <li><span>[+]</span> Gift of Lightning</li>
                        </ul>
                    <li><span>[+]</span> Gift of Mastery</li>
                    <li><span>[+]</span> Gift of Fortune</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="User2" class="area-right">
        <h1>User 2: Gylen</h1><br>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="GuildBank" class="container-bottom">
    <h1></h1>
</div>
```

Here's the script that I'm using:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function  () {
    var li_ul = document.querySelectorAll(".col_ul li ul");
    for (var i = 0; i < li_ul.length; i++) {
        li_ul[i].style.display = "none"
    };

    var exp_li = document.querySelectorAll(".col_ul li > span");
    for (var i = 0; i < exp_li.length; i++) {
        exp_li[i].style.cursor = "pointer";
        exp_li[i].onclick = showul;
    };
    function showul () {
        nextul = this.nextElementSibling;
        if(nextul.style.display == "block")
            nextul.style.display = "none";
        else
            nextul.style.display = "block";
    }}
</script>
```

For some reason, the `this.nextElementSibling` part works once but then gives me a null value for any of the other nested lists. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `<li><span>[+]</span> Bolt <ul> ...` vs. `<li><span>[+]</span> Gift of Bolt</li> <ul>`

Comment: `this` refers to `span` _in_ `li`, those `span`s triggering error currently don't have siblings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `null` on `this.nextElementSibling` because there is no next sibling that's an `element`!!

`<li><span>[+]</span> Gift of Bolt</li>`
If you look at this line you will find that you have already closed the `<li>` tagand hence there is no sibling for the `<span>` and you get a null. To fix this, simply wrap the `<ul>` next to the `<li>` inside `<li>...</li>`.

Check this solution on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qrotae7a/)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that `this` was referring to the `<span>` tag. I mistakenly thought it was pulling the `<li>` tag.